# Issues with reading Google Pay notifications from Android Notifications

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, google-pay

I am developing an android application I want to read the screen notifications from mobile.for that I have used notification Listener service and accessibility service. By using these two services I have read the notifications from all applications except Google Pay. For Google Pay it is showing **text** and **title** as **null**. Any help from experienced developers?

Comment: Please edit/share the code you have tried for reading which will help users to identify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you're trying to read Title and Text of some Notifications using getString as

```
sbn.getNotification().extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
```

You're trying to get a String but what notification actually contains is a Spannable String.

> android.text.SpannableString. This is the class for text whose content is immutable but to which markup objects can be attached and detached.

So you get an Exception as a Spannable String cannot be cast to String.
Instead use this,

```
String.valueOf(sbn.getNotification().extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE));
```

So basically you get the Spannable String first and convert it to a String using valueOf() method of String class.